# Android+Java get image from URL on server and pass as string to client: Base64 decode and encode not working

Tags: java, android, base64, android-imageview

In Java server I fetch image from external service URL like:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageWebServiceURL).openStream();
String resultToCleint = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
```

Then on Android I parse it like:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(resultToCleint.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Result: Image not displayed, ain't errors/exceptions neither on server nor on client.

What is the problem here?

EDIT: On android I use class `android.util.Base64`

Thanks,

Comment: let's assume `base64Content` in the base64 string reponsed from web service, you can use `byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Content, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);`

Comment: Moreover, if your server compressed reponse data either by gzip or deflate, your client side must decompressed the data first

Comment: @BNK it's not the case the response is regular Json

Comment: I know that, in my project, for example, `String base64Content = jsonObject.getString("Base64Content");`. My web service is Asp.Net Web API, and I used `Convert.ToBase64String(...)`

Comment: @BNK do you have answer for this question?

Comment: You mean I will add my comments as an answer?

Comment: @BNK if you know how to fix this so why not? Only via answer you can gain reputation etc.

Comment: I added, however, in mobile phone, it's difficult to format code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, let's assume `base64Content` is the base64 string responsed from your web service/server-side app, you can refer to the following sample code:

```
String base64Content = jsonObject.getString("Base64Content");
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Content, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Moreover, if your server compressed reponse data either by *gzip* or *deflate*, your client app must decompress the data first.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is exactly what I do in Android and it's not working

Comment: Any logcat information available or not? Have you checked your server side?

Comment: In your question, you used resultToCleint.getBytes(). Remove getBytes then check again.

Comment: I think the problem might be on the server side

Comment: Ok, post more code, both client side and server side. One more thing, have you tried to debug your app yet? Post the value of the variables too

Comment: The service url i'm using to get photos is google places photos search. they say the response is image. maybe here is the problem? necause image can have several formats? when I put the URL in the browser I get blank web page with only image https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Comment: So, if you have direct url that response the image, here is the binary data, not the base64 string, you can try loading it with Picasso or by using a volley/okhttp...request

Comment: but the url request must be on server side and then in some way pass the image via json

Comment: It depends on your requirement. As I said, if you have a direct link to the image, you can try Picasso, it's good :). I am busy now, I will reply your new comments soon, goodbye!

Comment: @BKN Maybe this approach will be better (my new question)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036066/java-google-places-photos-how-to-get-image-link

Comment: I have not ever tried that google service before. Tomorrow if have free time, i'll learn more

Answer (score 3):

Use Picasso library to load image:

You just need to add 1 line of code to show the image on ImageView

```
//Loading image from below url into imageView

Picasso.with(this)
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);
```

You can learn more from [here](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android)

Comment: The problem that here I don't have the url, rather the image data as decoded base64. so I thought maybe work with url link, and asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036066/java-google-places-photos-how-to-get-image-link

Answer (score 2):

**use this to convert to base 64**

```
public static String uploadPic(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = ""+ Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encoded;
    }


check if image is uploaded then using volley String request object download the string response using this code convert it back.

public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
   try {
      byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
      return bitmap;
   } catch(Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: the image url is external service and I have my own server (back end) making this calls to externals services in order to later pass them to android...